# Intercepting browser navigation event from FireBreath plugin

Tags: npapi, firebreath

I'm interested in receiving an event in my FireBreath plugin, when the user navigates to an URL.
Is this possible?
I couldn't find anything in the FireBreath Class Reference, and also not on Google.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, this is not possible.  What you want is an extension, not a plugin.  See http://npapi.com/extensions

Note that you can embed a plugin inside an extension.